# Bash sed: Replace all special characters (Invalid range end)

Tags: bash, sed

Ultimate goal is to replace line containing a password (which can contain any character) in a file:

```
...
passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]
...
```

I have string variables with replacements: 
(dont mind the double quotes for now)

`$old="passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]"`

`$new="passw=new#$#$@$#@%{}[]"`

If I use simple `sed -i "s#$old#$new#g" file.txt"` it obviously does't work properly as special characters break the syntax.

To make it work I need to escape all special characters with `\`, ex.: `\[`

I tried to use something like this:

```
esc=$("$old" | sed 's/[][`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}\|;:",<.>/?'"'"']/\\&/g'
```

However it gives me the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char42: Invalid range end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to escape the `/` in the search text when setting `esc`.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of markup, so `sed` ignores special characters in the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not achieve it without proper escaping. I tried sed, perl , etc but all of them break , especially in the chars {} and [].

You can apply a sed to escape all non usual chars at once.
In example bellow, i escape everything that is not text (a-z and A-Z) and is not a number (0-9)

```
$ cat file14
passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]

$ old='passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]' && echo "$old"  #mind the single quotes.
passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]

$ new='passw=new$#$#$$0-.?!@#$%^&*()_+@$#@%[]{}' && echo "$new"
passw=new$#$#$$0-.?!@#$%^&*()_+@$#@%[]{}

$ old=$(sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/\\&/g' <<<"$old") && echo "$old"
passw\=old\#\$\#\$\@\$\#\@\%\{\}\[\]

$ new=$(sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/\\&/g' <<<"$new") && echo "$new"
passw\=new\$\#\$\#\$\$0\-\.\?\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\@\$\#\@\%\[\]\{\}

$ sed -r "s/$old/$new/" file14
passw=new$#$#$$0-.?!@#$%^&*()_+@$#@%[]{}
```

Comment: I found this as the clearest approach to my goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

Note that the substitution is based on regex and special characters need to be escaped for search string in `awk` and for both search and replace strings in `sed`.  This requires preprocessing the strings.  Alternatively, if you input file is structured you can try string equality check

For example,

```
$ awk -v old='old#$#$@$#@%{}[]'    \
      -v new='[]{}new#$#$@$#@%'    \
      -v key='passw=' '"^"key{line=$0; 
                              sub(key,"",line); 
                              if(line==old) $0=key new}1' file
```

running on the input file

```
passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]
some other line with old#$#$@$#@%{}[]
```

will generate

```
pasw=[]{}new#$#$@$#@%
some other line with old#$#$@$#@%{}[]
```

you can also do the equality check on the complete `key=value` match as below

```
$ awk -v old='old#$#$@$#@%{}[]' \
      -v new='[]{}new#$#$@$#@%' \
      -v key='passw=' '$0==key old{$0=key new}1' file
```

or simplify further by search and replace strings include `key=` prefix

```
awk -v old='passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]' \
    -v new='passw=[]{}new#$#$@$#@%' \
          '$0==old{$0=new}1' file
```

these assume your password record is on a separate line.  If it's not a valid assumption you can set RS and ORS to `' '` and delete a last char of the output file (the last ORS added).  Another solution might be iterating over fields in a loop (e.g. `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==old) $i=new...`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im pretty new to bash, however I see this only replaces text within variable. I need to replace part of text inside a file. Btw, "old" and "new" parts of password are not static.

Comment: I tried your solution but gives error `"awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: Invalid content of \{\}: /passw=old#$#$@$#@%{}[]/"`

Comment: Where did the `/` come from?

Comment: No idea... Did you test it? If it works ok in your test, maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: But again, is strange . Have a look here to see what i get: http://pastebin.com/GEMM3mHz

Comment: You should only change the string "old" to string "new" and those should be variables. The special characters are not changing, only the alpha.

Comment: That means that every special char after old remains the same, but i think this is not the OP (deep) wish.

Comment: I might've misunderstood the question then. The example needs to cover the most general case...

Comment: Although I chose to go with George`s solution, I found your answer useful for general knowledge!